# how to debug core dump file generated from execute release file?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, coredump

I'm trying to figure out how to debug core files sent to me from my released versions of software (c code compiled with gcc).

I have a debug version (compiled with -g) of the executable, can I debug it?

Or is there a way to map between files to help with the debugging process.

Comment: If both the release and debug builds are exactly the same (apart from the debug information for the debug build) then you should be able to use the core.

Comment: thanks, but If both release and debug are not same, is it possible to debug it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a debug version (compiled with -g) of the executable, can I debug it?

No. The debug build will have different addresses for all the symbols, and GDB needs the correct mapping of symbols to code.

IF you compiled the binary with GCC, you *may* be able to rebuild it with *all* the original release flags and `-g`. The resulting executable *may* be close enough, though there are no guarantees.

Note: this currently doesn't currently work for Clang.

The best practice is to compile the binary with `-O2` (or whatever optimization you are using) and `-g` *together*, then `strip -g a.out -o a.out.release` and ship the `a.out.release` binary, while keeping the full-debug `a.out` for future debugging.

That way you *guarantee* that all the symbol addresses are identical between the released executable and your full-debug copy.

P.S. There are [ways to automate](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) finding correct full-debug copy for any given released binary, making it easier to be sure that the *correct* full-debug file is loaded for any given released binary.